# How to exclude assemblies by mask *.Tests.dll from TeamCity coverage with dotCover?

Tags: teamcity, mstest, code-coverage, dotcover

I'm using a naming convention for my test assemblies:

```
AssemblyOne.Tests.dll
ProjectTwo.AssemblyTwo.Tests.dll
...
```

I'm trying to  exclude the assemblies from coverage with the pattern in mstest runner with dotCover:

Assemblies Filter:

```
-:*.Tests.dll
```

I does not work, as i see coverage for the test methods in the test assemblies.
Please suggest a setting that would work. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assemblies filter accepts assembly names, not dll file names.
For example, instead of -:*.Tests.dll you need to specify:

```
 -:*.Tests
```